# Is there a localized membership status message in the framework?

Tags: localization, membership-provider

I'm using the membership provider to create a new user. The membership status I return can be any value from 0 to 11, each value being a different status.

Is there a way to get a localized message from that status from the managed code? I know how to hand code it, but I wondered if it's not allready localized and ready to use from somewhere in the framework.

For example, a success is a 0. Is there an associated message that will return that as a localized string in any language supported by the framework?

Thanks.

UPDATE: I'm using ASP.Net 3.5 with MVC 1.0

Comment: Yes, I'm using ASP.Net 3.5 with MVC 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have to translate them yourself, sorry.